# Summing Hours and Minutes in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

After running a query I am getting a Column Like one Below in MySQL

```
TimeDiff
03:45:07
03:28:59
00:36:16
00:59:42
02:44:18
```

Now I want to Sum up the Time together in the Same Query. A Sample Query is as given below

```
SELECT timediff(OutTime, InTime) AS TimeDiff
  FROM Table1
```

I tried Sum and SEC_TO_TIME but I am using in the wrong way.

Kindly let me know how to sum up the time to get 11:53:33

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(tbl.TimeDiff)) as TimeDifferent
FROM
  (SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(OutTime, InTime)) AS TimeDiff
   FROM Table1) as tbl
```